# Ajuda com INNER JOINS

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estou tendo um problema com o INNER JOIN.

Quando faço uma pesquisa por uma determinada venda ele me traz todas as vendas relacionadas ao código do cliente, pois é o campo “codcliente”  que associa as 03 tabelas (Cliente, Venda e ItemVenda), alem de pegar somente um valor total das vendas.

Estou publicando o endereço de acesso da página, para que os amigos possam analisar e quem sabe me dizer o que fazer para obter o resultado somente da venda pesquisada.

As vendas que estão cadastradas com o mesmo cliente são as 141, 146 e 147 todas cadastradas com o mesmo códcliente.

http://www.lccinformatica.com.br/prod_consulta_venda.php

Abaixo publico o código da pagina de pesquisa.

```
    <div align="left" style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"><h3>Consultar Venda</h3></div>

<div align="center" style=" padding:2px; width:655px; height:auto; float:left;">
    <div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:315px; height:auto; float:left;">
        <label>Entre com o código da Venda</label>
            <form action="prod_consulta_venda.php" name="busca" method="post">
            <input size="6" type="text" value="" name="buscar"/>
            <input type="submit" name="busca" value="Buscar Venda"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div align="left" style=" padding:2px; width:1000px; height:auto; border-top:solid 2px; float:left;">

<br />

<?php
    include 'conexao.php';

    if(isset($_POST['busca'])){
$buscar = $_POST['buscar']; 

$sql_listar = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cliente
INNER JOIN venda
ON cliente.codcliente = venda.codcliente
INNER JOIN itemvenda
ON cliente.codcliente = itemvenda.codcliente
WHERE venda.codvenda LIKE '%$buscar%'")or die(mysql_error());

$total_registros = mysql_num_rows($sql_listar);

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql_listar) <= 0){

        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= prod_consulta_venda.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Desculpe! Nenhuma Venda foi encontrada com esse código!');
</script>";

    }else{

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($sql_listar)){

        $conteudotabela1 .= '<tr style="color:#090;">

                <td align="center">'.$res['codvenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codcliente'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['datavenda'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['total'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['codproduto'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['quant'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['preco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['nome'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['endereco'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['bairro'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cidade'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['estado'].'</td>

                <td align="center">'.$res['cep'].'</td>

            </tr>';
    }}}


?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 15%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th style="width: 5%"></th>
            <th style="width: 5%">
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table class="tbllista" style="width: 100%">
    <thead>
        <tr align="center">
            <th align="center">Cód. Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Cliente</th>
            <th align="center">Data da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Total da Venda</th>
            <th align="center">Cód. Produto</th>
            <th align="center">Quantidade</th>
            <th align="center">Preço Unitário</th>
            <th align="center">Nome</th>
            <th align="center">Endereço</th>
            <th align="center">Bairro</th>
            <th align="center">Cidade</th>
            <th align="center">Estado</th>
            <th align="center">Cep</th>
         </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php echo $conteudotabela1; ?>

    </tbody>
```

A minha dúvida é como fazer para que eu receba somente os dados da venda consultada referente ao código da venda pesquisada, independente que seja do mesmo cliente ou não.

Agradeço a atenção de todos, já desejando Boas Festas.

Comment: Não tem fk de vendas na tabela itemvenda?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A modelagem correta de suas tabelas seria o código de cliente estar associado à venda (que é o cabeçalho) e cada item de venda (detalhes) estar associado à venda, algo assim:

```
TABELA cliente (codcliente, nome, etc)
TABELA venda (codcliente, numvenda, data, etc)
TABELA itemvenda (numvenda, codproduto, quantidade, etc)
```

Desta maneira o sql para procurar os dados seria adaptado como a seguir (retirado de seu código)

```
SELECT * FROM cliente
INNER JOIN venda
ON cliente.codcliente = venda.codcliente
INNER JOIN itemvenda
ON venda.numvenda = itemvenda.numvenda
WHERE venda.codvenda LIKE '%$buscar%'
```

Comment: Valeu Ademir, funcionou do jeito que imaginava, perfeito. Te agradeço pela ajuda. Boas festas de final de ano, e mais uma vez OBRIGADÃO.